# Is there a better way to go about this object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, object, init

I am fairly new to objects in Javascript, but I can already tell it's going to allow for a much more organized code structure. The problem I am having now is I don't really understand how I can utilize an object to perform the same basic function multiple times on the page. For example, the below script controls a carousel. It works fine if I just have one instance of this, but breaks with multiple carousels. Is there a better approach for this?

**Object Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var carousel = {
    config : {
        carouselDomContainer: $("#carousel-cont"),
        carouselImagesCont: $("#imgcont"),
        carouselDom: $("#carousel"),
        innerWrap: 'inner-wrap',
        outterWrap: "outter-img-container",
        slideDistance: 600,
        maxWidth: 650,
        maxHeight: 600,
        nextDom: "next",
        prevDom: "prev",

        $nextDom: function(){return $('#'+carousel.config.nextDom);},
        $prevDom: function(){return $('#'+carousel.config.prevDom);},
        $innerWrap: function(){return $('.'+carousel.config.innerWrap);},
        $outterWrap: function(){return $('.'+carousel.config.outterWrap);},

        wrapperHTML: function(){
            var options = carousel.config;
            return '<div id="'+options.prevDom+'" class="btn prev"><img src="http://www.the-leader.com/Global/images/ugc/leftarr_white.png" style="max-width:30%;margin-left:55%;"></div><div id="'+options.nextDom+'" class="btn next"><img src="http://www.the-leader.com/Global/images/ugc/rightarr_white.png" style="max-width:30%;margin-right:55%;"></div><div class="outter-wrap"><div class="'+options.innerWrap+'" style="height:100%;position:relative;"></div></div>';
        } 
    },

    init : function(config) {
        $.extend(carousel.config, config);
        carousel.buildWrapper();
        carousel.buildCarousel();
        carousel.buildUIActions();
        carousel.setStyles();
        carousel.insertBeforeFirst();
    },

    insertBeforeFirst: function(last,first){
        var indPane = carousel.config.$outterWrap();
        var indPaneFirst = indPane.first();
        var indPaneLast = indPane.last()
        $(indPaneLast).insertBefore(indPaneFirst);
    },

    setStyles: function(){
        var options = this.config;
        options.carouselDomContainer.css({
            width: options.maxWidth+'px',
            height: options.maxHeight+'px'
        });
        options.$innerWrap().css({left: '-'+options.slideDistance+'px', width: '3000px'});
    },

    buildUIActions: function(){
        var options = this.config;
        options.$nextDom().on("click",carousel.next);
        options.$prevDom().on("click",carousel.next);
    },

    buildWrapper: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        options.carouselDom.html(options.wrapperHTML());
    },

    buildCarousel: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        options.carouselImagesCont.find('li').each(function() {
            carousel.getContent($(this));
        });
        options.carouselImagesCont.remove();
    },

    getContent: function($li){
        var options = this.config;
        var htmlContent = '<div class="'+options.outterWrap+'" style="float:left;">';
                htmlContent += '<div class="inner-img-container" style="width:'+options.maxWidth+'px;height:'+options.maxHeight+'px;">';
                    htmlContent += '<img style="max-width:'+options.maxWidth+'px;max-height:'+options.maxHeight+'px;" src="'+$li.data('img')+'" />';
                    if($li.data('title')){htmlContent += '<div class="inner-text-container"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">'+$li.data('title')+'</span></div>';}
                    if($li.data('caption')){htmlContent += '<div class="inner-text-container"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">'+$li.data('caption')+'</span></div>';}
                htmlContent += '</div>';
            htmlContent += '</div>';
            carousel.drawContent(htmlContent);
    },

    drawContent: function($div){
        carousel.config.$innerWrap().append($div);
    },

    prev: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        var contDom = options.$innerWrap();
        var indPane = options.$outterWrap();
        var indPaneFirst = indPane.first();
        var indPaneLast = indPane.last()
        var Dist = options.slideDistance;
        contDom.animate({left:'+='+Dist}, "fast","swing", function(){
            indPaneLast.insertBefore(indPaneFirst);
            contDom.css({'left' : (Dist * (-1))});
        });
    },

    next: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        var contDom = options.$innerWrap();
        var indPane = options.$outterWrap();
        var indPaneFirst = indPane.first();
        var indPaneLast = indPane.last();
        var Dist = options.slideDistance;
        contDom.animate({left:'-='+Dist}, "fast", "swing", function(){
            indPaneFirst.insertAfter(indPaneLast);
            contDom.css({'left' : (Dist * (-1))});
        });
    }
}

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .carousel{width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:20px;float:left;background-color:#000;position:relative;}
    .carousel .prev{left:-6%;}
    .carousel .next{right:-6%;}
    .carousel .btn{width:13%;height:13%;position:absolute;top:40%;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;}
    .carousel .outter-wrap{width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;z-index:1}
    .carousel .inner-img-container{vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;text-align:center;position:relative;}
    .carousel .inner-text-container{width:95.5%;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);color:#FFF;z-index:5;padding:10px;font-size:12px;text-align:left;}

</style>

<div id="carousel-cont">
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel"></div>
    <ul id="imgcont">
        <li data-title="Some title goes here1" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://f52e304dfbaee0d644e5-e238cc27b87909affa90e9a9dd352aae.r50.cf1.rackcdn.com/152a8a72-aeed-42a7-99a3-ca4bd0680b55.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here2" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://familybugs.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/professional-group-of-five-for-web.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here3" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://groups.ku.edu/~deltasig/images/professional.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here4" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121103230308/sega/images/6/67/Sonic_Art_Assets_DVD_-_Sonic_The_Hedgehog_-_18.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**INIT**

```
carousel.init({
    carouselDomContainer: $("#carousel-cont"),
    carouselDom: $("#carousel"),
    carouselImagesCont: $("#imgcont"),
    innerWrap: 'inner-wrap',
    outterWrap: "outter-img-container",
    slideDistance: 630,
    maxWidth: 630,
    maxHeight: 400
});
```

I understand how to make this work for a single instance of the carousel, but I can't seem to wrap my brain around how this carousel object can be utilized for multiple carousels on the same page? Also, can anyone explain to me how I could easily add a function to this existing object, making the function available to any instance I call on this page? For example, if in this carousel function, I wanted to calculate the length. However, what if the calculate function wasn't declared in the original object. How can I add it once to this page and utilize it for all instances of this object?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: You should look up constructors for re-using the object, and it should also explain there that you can inherit methods from the prototype on the new instances.

Comment: Also stop using "id" attributes to identify target elements and start using classes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ids (#) use css class.

Try

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var carousel = {
    config : {
        carouselDomContainer: $(".carousel-cont"),
        carouselImagesCont: $(".imgcont"),
        carouselDom: $(".carousel"),
        innerWrap: 'inner-wrap',
        outterWrap: "outter-img-container",
        slideDistance: 600,
        maxWidth: 650,
        maxHeight: 600,
        nextDom: "next",
        prevDom: "prev",

        $nextDom: function(){return $('.'+carousel.config.nextDom);},
        $prevDom: function(){return $('.'+carousel.config.prevDom);},
        $innerWrap: function(){return $('.'+carousel.config.innerWrap);},
        $outterWrap: function(){return $('.'+carousel.config.outterWrap);},

        wrapperHTML: function(){
            var options = carousel.config;
            return '<div id="'+options.prevDom+'" class="btn prev"><img src="http://www.the-leader.com/Global/images/ugc/leftarr_white.png" style="max-width:30%;margin-left:55%;"></div><div id="'+options.nextDom+'" class="btn next"><img src="http://www.the-leader.com/Global/images/ugc/rightarr_white.png" style="max-width:30%;margin-right:55%;"></div><div class="outter-wrap"><div class="'+options.innerWrap+'" style="height:100%;position:relative;"></div></div>';
        } 
    },

    init : function(config) {
        $.extend(carousel.config, config);
        carousel.buildWrapper();
        carousel.buildCarousel();
        carousel.buildUIActions();
        carousel.setStyles();
        carousel.insertBeforeFirst();
    },

    insertBeforeFirst: function(last,first){
        var indPane = carousel.config.$outterWrap();
        var indPaneFirst = indPane.first();
        var indPaneLast = indPane.last()
        $(indPaneLast).insertBefore(indPaneFirst);
    },

    setStyles: function(){
        var options = this.config;
        options.carouselDomContainer.css({
            width: options.maxWidth+'px',
            height: options.maxHeight+'px'
        });
        options.$innerWrap().css({left: '-'+options.slideDistance+'px', width: '3000px'});
    },

    buildUIActions: function(){
        var options = this.config;
        options.$nextDom().on("click",carousel.next);
        options.$prevDom().on("click",carousel.next);
    },

    buildWrapper: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        options.carouselDom.html(options.wrapperHTML());
    },

    buildCarousel: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        options.carouselImagesCont.find('li').each(function() {
            carousel.getContent($(this));
        });
        options.carouselImagesCont.remove();
    },

    getContent: function($li){
        var options = this.config;
        var htmlContent = '<div class="'+options.outterWrap+'" style="float:left;">';
                htmlContent += '<div class="inner-img-container" style="width:'+options.maxWidth+'px;height:'+options.maxHeight+'px;">';
                    htmlContent += '<img style="max-width:'+options.maxWidth+'px;max-height:'+options.maxHeight+'px;" src="'+$li.data('img')+'" />';
                    if($li.data('title')){htmlContent += '<div class="inner-text-container"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">'+$li.data('title')+'</span></div>';}
                    if($li.data('caption')){htmlContent += '<div class="inner-text-container"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">'+$li.data('caption')+'</span></div>';}
                htmlContent += '</div>';
            htmlContent += '</div>';
            carousel.drawContent(htmlContent);
    },

    drawContent: function($div){
        carousel.config.$innerWrap().append($div);
    },

    prev: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        var contDom = options.$innerWrap();
        var indPane = options.$outterWrap();
        var indPaneFirst = indPane.first();
        var indPaneLast = indPane.last()
        var Dist = options.slideDistance;
        contDom.animate({left:'+='+Dist}, "fast","swing", function(){
            indPaneLast.insertBefore(indPaneFirst);
            contDom.css({'left' : (Dist * (-1))});
        });
    },

    next: function(){
        var options = carousel.config;
        var contDom = options.$innerWrap();
        var indPane = options.$outterWrap();
        var indPaneFirst = indPane.first();
        var indPaneLast = indPane.last();
        var Dist = options.slideDistance;
        contDom.animate({left:'-='+Dist}, "fast", "swing", function(){
            indPaneFirst.insertAfter(indPaneLast);
            contDom.css({'left' : (Dist * (-1))});
        });
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i've tried this already. The IDs are only effected when 2 of the same Dom's have the same ID. I don't do anything like that, but I still can't get this to work correctly. When I run this script, I get 2 carousels, styling is good. However, when I click the 'Next' or 'Prev' buttons, it only effects the last created carousel. I just need to figure out he best way to write object oriented javascript so I can use these multiple times on the same page....and edit/update as necessary

Comment: the Next or Prev buttons are also hooked to ids "options.prevDom" and "options.nextDom" inside wrapperHTML function so the carousel which was created last will acquire the ids and not the previous ones.

Comment: Yes, but I pass those into the config (if necessary). So for example if I want, I allow the user to call those next1, next2, etc. I've tried adding multiple versions, all with different IDs for everything, still no dice.

Comment: you will need to use "this" object and find the next and prev buttons using their unique classes. e.g. prev: "btn prev", next: "btn next". final pseudo code: $(this).find("btn prev").click(function() {do something});

Comment: Something like this?

options.$nextDom().on("click",function(){
 $(this).find(".next").click(function(){
  alert('clicked this next btn');
 });
});

Comment: Tried that like 12 different ways (even tried using nested functions there) and couldn't get it to work. This still only answers a portion of the overall question though.